# Using a Hyperlink in an Input Message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my current spreadsheet, when you enter in a certain value a input message will be displayed. However, the input message should have a link in it which takes you to another tab.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
 if (cellSheet !== sheet && cellColumn === 4) {
if (cellValue === "PT1 - Induction Training") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT1 - Induction Training: This is a Theory Based course and does not require you to be on the server. It should take 15-20 minutes.)");  //Add the course name and the message that I want to popup. Course name should be exactly the same as in the list (case sensitive)
} 

else if (cellValue === "PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 1") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 1 - Starting a Patrol: This is a Practical Based course and does require you to be on the server. It should take 10-15 minutes. The manual for this course can be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EUAtzKHaDXGMJLcGy5usXiHE7QU7B7g98OSUuKd94ss/edit");  //// add as many "else if" conditions as you want"
} else if (cellValue === "PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 2") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 2 - Traffic Stops: This is a Practical Based course and does require you to be on the server. It should take 10-15 minutes. The manual for this course can be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EUAtzKHaDXGMJLcGy5usXiHE7QU7B7g98OSUuKd94ss/edit");   
} else if (cellValue === "PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 3") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 3 - Checkpoints: This is a Practical Based course and does require you to be on the server. On average, it takes around an HOUR to do, so please bare in mind if you are able to do it. The manual for this course can be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EUAtzKHaDXGMJLcGy5usXiHE7QU7B7g98OSUuKd94ss/edit");   
} else if (cellValue === "PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 4") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 4 - Basic Communication: This is a Theory Based course and does not require you to be on the server. It should take 10-15 minutes. The manual for this course can be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EUAtzKHaDXGMJLcGy5usXiHE7QU7B7g98OSUuKd94ss/edit");   
} else if (cellValue === "PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 5") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 5 - Communication with Officers: This is a Theory Based course and does not require you to be on the server. It should take 10-15 minutes.The manual for this course can be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EUAtzKHaDXGMJLcGy5usXiHE7QU7B7g98OSUuKd94ss/edit");   
} else if (cellValue === "PT3 - Officer Advancement - Part 1") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT3 - Officer Advancement - Part 1: This is a Theory Based course and does not require you to be on the server. It should take 25-30 minutes.");   
} else if (cellValue === "PT3 - Officer Advancement - Part 2") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT3 - Officer Advancement - Part 2: This is a Practical Based course and does require you to be on the server. On average, it takes around an HOUR to do, so please bare in mind if you are able to do it.");   
} else if (cellValue === "PT4 - Air Support ") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT4 - Air Support: This is a Practical Based course and does require you to be on the server. It should take around 30-40 minutes");   
} else if (cellValue === "PT5 - Interceptors") {
  Browser.msgBox("PT5 - Interceptors: This is a Practical Based course and does require you to be on the server. It should take around 40-50 minutes");   
} 


  else if (cellValue === undefined) {  }
else {
  Browser.msgBox("You have entered an invalid course, please select a correct course.");   //This is in case they put a wrong course name
}
}
}
```

Where the links are, at the end of the messages, for example: "The manual can be viewed here:", I would like them to form a hyper link, so when clicked on, takes you to that manual.

Here's the link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QBVvQkkmLJ3Ro2uHAmQm2yulmJ8Tg38p5Ke3YIe-FwI/edit#gid=1161230471

Many Thanks,

Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the [alert dialogue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs), which will not allow you to add a link.

Instead, I imagine you're looking to create a [custom HTML dialogue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) which will allow you to create the HTML for the dialogue box, allowing you to use an  tag for links.

Note: It's been some time since I checked, but I think Apps script displays a warning to the user when clicking on a link like this.